# Как мне удалить счета — crypto pay api?

Tags: python

Ошибка следующего плана:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытаюсь удалять неактивные счета , используя асинхронную библиотеку: aiocryptopay .

В этом коде я получаю все счета в формате списка, затем ищу invoice_id, и потом эти invoice_id подставляю к методу для удаления счета, но он не удаляется. Я уверен, что invoice_id я передаю правильный, пытался по одному удалять - ничего, пытался получить данные счетов и с консоли копировал айди счета и подставлял для одиночного удаления - тоже ничего.

```
import asyncio
from aiocryptopay import AioCryptoPay, Networks
from config import TEST_CRYPTO_BOT_API

crypto = AioCryptoPay(token=TEST_CRYPTO_BOT_API, network=Networks.TEST_NET)

async def deleteInvoices():
    invoices = await crypto.get_invoices()

    for i in invoices:
        try:
            print(i.invoice_id)
            await crypto.delete_invoice(i.invoice_id)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Ошибка при обработке инвойса {i.invoice_id}: {e}")
            continue

    await crypto.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(deleteInvoices())
```